# Container that runs any process without internet access

Tags: windows

Does anyone know of a `portable` application that can run any other application while denying it internet access? If no, are there alternative methods such as automatically checking if firewall rules for the selected exe(s) exist, and if not add it? Or maybe run the exe(s) through cmd.exe with arguments that disallow it access to the internet.

Anyone know of such an application/method/etc ?

Comment: Why not use windows firewall to block that particular application? http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall.html , else you could make a script to do the same thing. ultimately portability will be limited to windows.

Comment: @u8sand I understand that I can block the program manually through the firewall settings but I'm looking for an automated solution so that no matter on what machine I start the application (either directly or through a script, doesn't matter); there should not be any internet connection allowed via said application.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 32-bit Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326).

Use the [`ipsec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490922.aspx) filter command line – add disable MS SQL port filter:

```
IPSeccmd.exe -w REG -p "SQL Server Block" -r "Block Outbound UDP 1433 Rule" -f 0=*:1433:UDP -n BLOCK -r "Block Outbound TCP 1433 Rule" -f 0=*:1433:TCP -n BLOCK

netsh firewall set allowedprogram "path\appname.exe" "Name" disable
```

See also:

- [Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall Commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [How to use the "netsh advfirewall firewall" context instead of the "netsh firewall" context to control Windows Firewall behavior in Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709)

Comment: I've used netsh before to semi-automatically block internet access to certain applications but I need a way to detect if said rule is already present because else a duplicate one gets added each time I run the script.

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all` search program name ... `netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging filename "C:\Log\fire.log"` see log. May bee use another software?))

Comment: It'd be great if you could embed the links you post into readable text, and not just drop a few links and command lines, but explain what these do and how to use them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file to block the application with the windows firewall, this might require administrative privileges though reducing its portability.

This would be an example batch script (has not been tested as I do not have a windows system available):

```
@echo off
set rule=block_prog
set prog=your_program.exe

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%rule%" dir=in program="%prog%" action="block" enable="yes"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="%rule%" dir=out program="%prog%" action="block" enable="yes"
start /b %prog%
exit
```

Comment: I've been doing something similar but this will create duplicate rules each time I run the script; I need it added once and only once.